# (Errno 10048) Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: localhost, websocket

I'm trying to use MkDocs and when I run:

```
mkdocs serve
```

I get the following output:

```
INFO    -  Building documentation...
INFO    -  Cleaning site directory
[I 180130 17:24:42 server:283] Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

I can't find the way what other services are using/running on that ip/socket.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: windows, thanks. I've already figured it out, virtualbox was causing the problem.

Comment: Please post an answer if possible. Otherwise please close the question since it won't get other meaningful answers given you've solved it.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution:

1. Run `resmon` for resource monitor dialog
2. On `Network` tab search for `Listening ports` section
3. Look for the one taking `8000` port (in my case it was a `virtualbox` instance)
4. Turn it off and it will work.